# Take keys from Dictionary and map them to an array

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, closures

I'm trying to build a closure that does what my title says. My code runs but it does not print what I expected.

```
var names: [String] = []
var namesAndAges = ["Tom": 25, "Michael": 35, "Harry": 28, "Fabien": 16]

var ofAge = namesAndAges.filter { namesAndAges in namesAndAges.value > 18 }

var addNames = ofAge.map { ofAge in names.append(ofAge.key) }

print(addNames) //this prints [(), (), ()]
```

Comment: Update your question with the output you want to get. What should actually be in `addNames`?

Comment: It should print only the names from the namesAndAges dictionary

Comment: `names.append(ofAge.key)` returns `Void` (a.k.a. the empty tuple, `()`). `map` produces a new Array containing the return values of the given closure after it's been applied to every element of the source array (`ofAge`, in your example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are misusing filter and map methods.
Try this:

```
var names: [String] = []
var namesAndAges = ["Tom": 25, "Michael": 35, "Harry": 28, "Fabien": 16]

var ofAge = namesAndAges.filter { $0.value > 18 }

var addNames = ofAge.map { $0.key }

print(addNames) //this prints ["Michael", "Harry", "Tom"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're experience is because `names.append(ofAge.key)` returns `Void` (a.k.a. the empty tuple, `()`). `map` produces a new `Array` containing the return values of the given closure after it's been applied to every element of the source array (`ofAge`, in your example).

The `names` array will actually contain the data you want, but this isn't how `map` is meant to be used (you're essentially using it in place of `forEach`).

Try this instead:

```
var namesAndAges = ["Tom": 25, "Michael": 35, "Harry": 28, "Fabien": 16]
var namesOfAge = namesAndAges.filter { $0.value > 18 }.map{ $0.key }

print(namesOfAge)
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid looping more than once, this is how I do it:

```
var namesAndAges = ["Tom": 25, "Michael": 35, "Harry": 28, "Fabien": 16]
let addNames: [String] = namesAndAges.flatMap { $0.value > 18 ? $0.key : nil }
print(addNames) // prints ["Michael", "Harry", "Tom"]
```

(oh and it's shorter )